# Insert into one table and update another table in a for loop

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different tables. I use a for loop for inserting and updating both tables

It's an example:

```
   for (int i=0; i<multientryindex;++i)
   {
      data1= _listBox[0].Items[i].ToString();
      data2= _listBox[1].Items[i].ToString();
      // same for other datas
      cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO (field1,field2) VALUES (@data1,@data2)");
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1",data1);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2",data2);
     try
     {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch(MySqlException e)
     {
     }
     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     qty = int.Parse(data2);
     cmd = MySqlCommand("UPDATE depo SET qty=qty - @adqty WHERE prodid=@prodid ...");
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adqty",qty);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodid",prodid);     //That
     try
     {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch(MySqlException e)
     {
     }
     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   }
```

When I include Update query in the loop Mysql ask to place "That" in first parameters. However this data is not included with another name in first cmd command. And the result is catastrophic.

But if I do  same with two for loop different the result is good.

MySql can't operate in the same loop an Insert and an Update with same connection ?

Here is the given error. @adqty does'nt exist in first command string. However mysql tells me to add it within the first parameters, when this 2 commands are in the same for loop.

[image]

Comment: Have try using trigger?

Comment: what language is this? C#?

Comment: you don't have any `prodid` variable in second query, please do not cut important information.

Comment: I completed. It exists. My problem prodid does not exist in first cmd command,  mysql asks me to add it in first parameters. It already exists in second part of parameters and I need there. If I place second command in an other loop everything is well.

Comment: really, I can not follow your coding, I can't see how `prodid` initialized and your complete code. Again, Why you not just post the related code as complete one, so we can check all variables and query? Why not just post the error interpreted by compiler instead translate it into your own language which we are not understand?

Comment: I did a mistake it's not the good method (if you took my precedent reply) this is this one : http://turcguide.com/stack/originalcode.txt
As I did a mistake the method name is save multiple. If you have this. That's ok.